# Scala mock not mocking extended class function?

Tags: scala, mockito

Here is how the code looks:

```
class B {
    doStuff() //some API call
}
class A extends B {
    val x = doStuff()
    ...
}
```

When I mock it as follows:

```
class ASpec {
    val a = new A
    when(a.doStuff()).thenReturn("stuff") <---this should just return "stuff" on the test
    assert(true, a.doOtherStuff())
}
```

Problem is that its definitely still making the API call from doStuff(). How come its not returning "stuff" as specified?

Comment: Where is `doStuff` declared? If you mean that it is in `B`, that isn't clear (you need a `def`, at least). It would be nice to see a minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `A` a mock. Right now, you're creating a real instance of `A` via `new A`. Instead, use `mock(classOf[A])` (or, with ScalaTest's [MockitoSugar](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar), `mock[A]`):

```
val a = mock(classOf[A])
when(a.doStuff()).thenReturn("stuff")
when(a.doOtherStuff()).thenCallRealMethod() // Necessary since `A` is a mock
assert(a.doOtherStuff())
```

**However**, it's generally a Bad Idea™ to mock one method of a class so that you can test another. For one thing, you'll need to remember to specify the behavior of each method of `A` used by `doOtherStuff` (potentially using `thenCallRealMethod` on all of them). Prefer only mocking things external to your class. To accomplish this, you can either mock what `doStuff` depends on or move `doStuff` to another class.